# Lwip client with RTOS

Tags: tcp, client, freertos, lwip

I was trying to write a code for client using lwip/tcp. I had problem with tcp_connect function, error 252. Then I found out I can't use it with FreeRTOS in its usual way. Can someone provide me a hint or if there is any, example for this?

Thanks,
Ana

Comment: what does _Here, everything is fine until tcp_connect_ mean? are there errors?

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The lwip has 3-level API:

1. Callback-style API or RAW API - when you allocate pcbs, uses callbacks for events. It API isn't thread-safe and haven't used with RTOS.
2. netconn API - thread-safe API which should be used with RTOS (opt NO_SYS=0). Most used as I know.
3. socket API - thread-safe API similar to BSD-Sockets which should used with RTOS (opt NO_SYS=0).

So with FreeRTOS you should use netconn API or socket API.
Please check first https://lwip.fandom.com/wiki/Netconn_API

For examples - please check your vendor of MCU examples. If it doesn't exist - check out examples from STM32 for example https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00103685-developing-applications-on-stm32cube-with-lwip-tcp-ip-stack-stmicroelectronics.pdf